# Start IntelliJ run-configuration from command line

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I work on a Kotlin-based cloud microservice. From time to time I need to run it in the IntelliJ debugger, but we often accidentally break the "local debug flow". There is no pipeline that checks if the IntelliJ run-configuration and the somewhat complex set of cloud-simulating proxies and mock-servers are in sync with the code base.

I would like to write a script that helps me check if the local debug flow works. The script should do the following:

1. build the project
2. start up the "mock cloud"
3. start the service locally using an IntelliJ run-configuration
4. run a Postman-collection against the locally running service

I need help with step 3 (and possibly step 1): How can I start the IntelliJ run-configuration via command line? I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2 and MacOS 12.3.1.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to start a Run Configuration from the command line. Instead, you should execute java/kotlin binary with classpath etc.

For example, for "Application" configuration it is needed to run the command like that:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! But the classpath is quite dynamic -- can you think of a way to generate/update the classpath via a script so that I don't have to copy/paste it every few days? (Forgetting to keep the classpath inside the script in sync will otherwise lead to subtle "bugs" that aren't real bugs.)

Comment: Why it is dynamic? What is the trigger for classpath changes? You can program that trigger in your script.

Comment: Not super dynamic - but at least once per week we use a different version or different library.